# MATLAB: "Loading" a function for fast access

Tags: matlab, performance, function, memory-management, scope

I have to write a fairly complicated function in MATLAB; let's call this `f`. And I have a main program, say `main.m`, which makes use of `f`.

If I am to follow my past habit, whenever dealing with a complicated function like `f`, I write it down in a separate file `f.m` and call on it whenever I need it from within `main.m`. But for the problem at hand, I will have to use `f` * a lot * and I'm afraid that reading from disk will slow down my code which is already taking a long time to run.

So I'd like to ask please if this is a valid concern: i.e., does MATLAB (say 2017a or later) read from disk each time I command it to use `f` from within `main.m` or does it do something smarter? If the former is true, what is the efficient way (time-wise) to use `f` many times from within `main.m`? Does either of these answer change if `f` is iterative (i.e. `f` calls itself)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB loads and parses a function M-file the first time it is called, and stores it in memory in a way that subsequent calls do not need to parse it again. You can see that this is true by calling your function `f` in a clean MATLAB session twice, using `tic`/`toc` to time it:

```
tic; f(...); toc
tic; f(...); toc
```

The first time it should take a little longer than the second time. For a very quick function this time difference will be very large. For a function that takes many seconds the difference might be meaningless.

You can see which functions are loaded in memory using the function [`inmem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inmem.html).

When you call [`clear all` or `clear functions`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html), functions are erased from memory (some other forms of `clear` also erase functions). Avoid using these.

Comment: Thanks Cris. Does this mean defining a function within a program (in my case, defining `f` within `main.m`) carries no intrinsic performance advantage? (Of course, that reduces the number of files.) Put differently, does this mean, for the problem described above, I can carry on with my modular approach (i.e. `f` on a separate `f.m`) without worrying about performance hit?

Comment: @yurnero: There are different things to think about there. (1) There shouldn't be a time difference to execute a function within the same file or a separate file, once that file is loaded. (2) When defining `f` within the `main.m` file, it will be parsed when `main` is executed, so the **first time** `main` calls `f`, it will be (very slightly) faster than if `f` is in `f.m`. (3) I'm not sure about this point, but I presume that, the more M-files you have, the longer it takes for MATLAB to find the right file to run it. A few additional files should not matter though.

Comment: So I'd say yes, carry on. Do you know about the `private` directory?

Comment: Do you refer to this: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/private-functions.html? I see what is being said but I'm afraid I cannot connect how it is related to our topic. Could you please explain?

Comment: @yurnero: It's not related to efficiency at all, but it's a nice way to split functionality across files keeping only a single entry point. You can make `f` a private function by sticking it in a subdirectory `private` next to `main.m`. `main` will be able to call it, but your users won't be able to call it directly. This might or might not be meaningful in your case, it's just a suggestion since you are splitting your code across files.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I understand things much better now and I can proceed with confidence. Cheers.